# Excel: Can we prevent Paste Operation on cells

Tags: excel

I have made one worksheet. And there I don't have option for Macro Enabled, as It is going to be distributed among lots of users to fill the information.

Now the question is, there are some data validation fields in worksheet.

If I do copy any data and paste on that field column, it takes any values in that, which is not correct.

Is there any way to prevent paste on cells without Macro code?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of the second answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020031/how-to-prevent-the-update-of-a-cell-in-excel?rq=1  ?

Comment: You would need a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent ANY data entry in those cells you can mark them as locked & protect the sheet with a password.

If you want to allow editing those cells but need to validate that only certain data is allowed, you can use Data Validation, Custom & enter a formula.
You won't be able to use custom VBA functions but most standard Excel functions should work.